# Finding a software restriction policy created by Windows 7 in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy

On a computer originally set up with Windows 7, I created a Limited User account for my child and only allowed a handful of programs to run.

This computer has now been updated to Windows 10 (currently Build 14393.187) and I want to add another program. However, after installation, the program cannot be run.

The event viewer has an event with Id 882: `Access to C:\Program Files (x86)\{program.exe} has been restricted by your Administrator by policy rule {b8da5363-dd99-4a61-88e0-fda6064fa530}.`

How do I find this policy to either change or delete it? The UI for limited/child accounts from Windows 7 is no longer available, and I cannot find anything under `Software Restriction Policies` for that particular user.

<strike>I also tried to search the registry with the policy GUID, but to no avail.</strike> I'd forgotten to load the user hive, now the GUID shows up under `HKU/Software/Policies/Windows/Safer`.

Comment: Is there anything relevant under that user's `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\safer`?

Comment: "However, after installation, the program cannot be run." - Which program?

Comment: @BenN Actually, yes. There are a bunch of subkeys with all the whitelisted apps. Where do I go from here? Can I just delete the whole "safer" branch to remove all restrictions, or is there more to it?

Comment: What did you use to prevent the user from running the applications exactly?  Windows 10 Family Account (or whatever its called) requires the user to connected to a MS account.  How you allowed certain applications should be the reltively the same.

Comment: @Ramhound As I said, I set up the family restrictions back when the computer was on Windows 7. The way this work changed in Windows 10. I don't have any family restrictions on Windows 10, as far as the Control Panel or Settings app is concerned.

Comment: @JensNeubauer - How its configured has changed in Windows 10, its documented, you were not really specific on how you configured it.  There is third-party software that you could have used.  That is the reason I asked for these clafifications.

Comment: Removing the `safer` branch *might* do it, depending on your edition. What edition of Windows do you have (e.g. Home, Professional)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Policy Registry values can either be set through POL files or directly. If they're set via POL files, the Registry values might come back if you delete them but not the original POL.

Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers` (a hidden folder). Look for a folder named the target user's SID. If you don't know the SID, look it up with `wmic useraccount get name, sid` in a command prompt. If the SID-named subfolder is present, delete it. That destroys the per-user policy settings. If there is no such folder, no problem.

Then delete the `safer` branch of the target user's hive. (If you might want to get anything out of it later, export it first.) After a reboot, that user will no longer be subject to any per-user Software Restriction Policies.